# Creating smooth text borders with CSS

Tags: css, ios

I'm making an **iPhone** lockscreen based on [this image](http://www.maggadget.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/wp7lockscreen.jpg).
So far, what I've come up with [looks like this](http://i1214.photobucket.com/albums/cc490/KeyMs92/Lockscreen.png).

Although, they look pretty similar in terms of layout the first one is slick and other rather ugly :P. I believe this as everything to do with the smoothness of the text borders. (Believe it or not, the font is exactly the same!) I'm now using this:

```
text-shadow: -1px 0 #585858, 0 1px #585858, 1px 0 #585858, 0 -1px #585858;
```

But as you can see it doesn't look great. Is there a way to add some kind of anti aliasing?

Here's a short demo:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body { position: absolute; background-color: #000; font-family: Calibri; color: #fff; text-shadow: -1px 0 #585858, 0 1px #585858, 1px 0 #585858, 0 -1px #585858; }
#clock { position: absolute; width: 290px; top: 50%; margin: -0.7em 0 0 30px; font-size: 53px; }
#day { line-height: 0.8; font-size: 0.9em; }
#date { position: absolute; margin-top: 18px; line-height: 0.6; font-size: 103px; }
</style>
</head>   
<body>
<img src="http://tiny.cc/47nz6" width="320" height="480">
<div id="clock">5:30 AM
    <div id="day">Wednesday
    </div>
    <div id="date">14 Dec
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It depends what platform it's on. A general solution is to add a semi-transparent text shadow with an `rgba()` colour. Have you tried that?

Comment: Do you have access to Javascript?

Comment: JamWaffles, I tried a semi-transparent shadow but TBH it makes the the border look more flimsy (and not smoother). Purmou, yes I'm using Javascript, also for the font. If it helps, I added a short version of the code and the full version to download.

Comment: Thanks roXon, sorry totally forgot about that. I'll update my previous questions.

Answer (score 0):

With out providing a demo I cant really test this, but you could try something like:

```
font-smooth:always;
```

or

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

Comment: Thanks, `font-smooth:always;` seemed to have no effect. I haven't tried the second one, but do you know if that if will work on the iPhone? (I suspect not)

Comment: @KeyMs92 I dont know if it will fix your problem, but it should work as iPhone is webkit